# align submit and cancel button with bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap 2.0` within my rails app (using the `bootstrap-sass` gem) and am having trouble getting a submit button aligned with a cancel button.

Here's the code snippet from the form in the html.erb file:

```
<div class="span3">
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here's the HTML it produces:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Person" name="commit">
<button class="btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

And here's what it looks like in firefox 14.0.1. When I look at the

[image: pic of mis-aligned buttons]

Note: Adding input-append to the div gets me close (see pic below) but is still off a bit--note that cancel is still a bit lower and that the rounded corners on the right side of the add person button are cut off.

[image]

How can I get these two buttons to align properly?

**Update**
I am using Firefox 14.0.1. When I look at the jsfiddle created by @Vestride to duplicate this problem here's what I see:

[image]

I am happy with the first result, but when I add the exact same code to my site, I don't get the same result. Instead I get the messed up alignment above. I wonder what this means? Maybe that my CSS for bootstrap is messed up?

**Update 7/27**
In response to Vestride's latest suggestion, here are the buttons as they show in my Firefox from the fiddle Vestride put together. Note, there's no improvement with changing from input to submit. 
[image]

Comment: Have you modified any property of the buttons? That's not normal

Comment: I didn't think I had... maybe the right next step is for me to start with an empty rails app, add the bootstrap gem and see if I still get the problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what the problem is. Opera has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vestride/YT3sq but was unable to duplicate your problem. They align perfectly for me (Chrome 21). What browser are you using? In the second example I added a `btn-group` class to the container element. That might also solve your problem.

Edit:
Try making your `<input />` a `<button type="submit">`. Worked in Firefox for me. I updated the fiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old issue, but using Bootstrap 4 I had the same problem. What solved it for me is adding `margin-bottom: 0` or `mb-0` class using bootstrap classes on the **submit button**.